# What flooring material is best for cleaning off cat pee?

Tags: cats, cleaning, urination

I have two healthy 6yo cats, a spayed/neutered sister and brother. One litter box is in a large master bathroom. The other is in the shower area of a small bathroom. The cats have no trouble getting to it and use it, but they also pee on the wooden floor. We've tried everything but can't stop them. I'd like to replace the (ruined) wooden floor with tiles or some other material that is easier to clean. What would be the best material for discouraging or cleaning off cat pee?

Answer (score 3):

There's specific enzymatic sprays that react with, and remove the smell of pee, so in theory they're less likely to pee there. If there's pee smell, they will pee. Tiles *are* better since the pee won't soak into it, but most animals tend to pee in the same places so destroying the smell is important.

The products you'd have depend on the market you're in, but the stuff we bought was labelled 'urine eliminator' and purchased at a pet store.